# sql deletion run time error with php

Tags: php, html

I have a validation problem with my php file.. the coding is given below

```
<html>
<head>
<body>
</body>
<form method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>">
Enter ID:
<input type="text" name="Delete">
<input type="submit" value="OK">
</form>
<?php
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST")
{
$servername="localhost";
$username="root";
$password="";
$dbname="Ystock";
$delete=$_REQUEST["Delete"];
if($delete=="")
{
echo"Please Enter a correct ID";
}
else
{

$conn=mysqli_connect($servername,$username,$password,$dbname);
if(!$conn)
{
die("Connection Failed!".mysqli_error($conn));
}

$sql="DELETE FROM  total WHERE ID='$delete'";
if(mysqli_query($conn,$sql))
{
echo "Data deleted";
}
else 
{
echo"Error in delete".mysqli_error($conn);
}
mysqli_close($conn);

}
}
else
{
}
?>
</body>
</head>
</html>
```

The problem is that,whenwver I try to input a Id no. to delete a record though it's not present in the "ID" column,it shows the message "Data Deleted".For example If I delete ID 1 then it get delete n shows the message "data deleted".But if I put ID 1 again to delete then also It shows the message "data Delete".. please help me out.

Comment: you want to use [`mysqli_affected_rows ( mysqli $link )`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.affected-rows.php) to check how many rows were affected by your `DELETE` query.

Comment: Thanx.. but I m confuse...ac2ly I am new in PHP so I hve no idea how to write the statement even I checked in google also but i cudnt catch...so if u dont mind can u please write the code as a hint..sorry. :)

Comment: Inside your `if(mysqli_query($conn,$sql)){...}` change `{ echo "Data deleted";}` to `if(mysqli_affected_rows($conn) > 0) { echo "Data deleted";} else { "Row does not exist, 0 rows deleted";}`.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use mysqli_affected_rows function to check if the query has really deleted a row

Comment: Also, your code is very dangerous ! Take care about security, a user can delete your whole database. Take also care of SQL injection !